# Image uploading on Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-image

Does anybody have an idea about [this website](http://blog.3pillarglobal.com/part-3-using-socialauth-integrate-twitter-api-android)?

I am trying the code provided here, the status uploading looks fine but i can't upload any image seems as if `UploadImageAsyn()` is not working. Here's my code

```
public class ShareButtonActivity extends Activity {
// SocialAuth Component
SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
Bitmap bitmap;

// Android Components
Button update;
EditText edit;
ImageView img;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.buildDrawingCache();
        bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();

    // Create Your Own Share Button
    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
    share.setText("Share");

    // Add it to Library
    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

    // Add providers
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);

    // Enable Provider
    adapter.enable(share);
}

/**
 * Listens Response from Library
 * 
 */

private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        // Get name of provider after authentication
             final String providerName=values.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);
        Log.d("ShareButton", "Provider Name = " + providerName);
        Toast.makeText(ShareButtonActivity.this, providerName + " connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    adapter.uploadImageAsync("Landscape Images", "icon.png", bitmap, 0,new UploadImageListener());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yoohooo ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
        Log.d("ShareButton", "Authentication Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("ShareButton", "Authentication Cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        Log.d("Share-Button", "Dialog Closed by pressing Back Key");
    }

}

// To get status of message after authentication
private final class UploadImageListener implements SocialAuthListener<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void onExecute(String provider, Integer t) {

         Log.d("Custom-UI", "Uploading Data");
          Integer status = t;
          Log.d("Custom-UI", String.valueOf(status));
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

}

Every time i click the update button a "no" message is printed on toast. Although the program does not show any error. I would be really greatfull if anybody can help me out on this.

Comment: Hi @Prince, I notice you making lots of tag edits of questionable quality on questions. Please don't add tags like `div` to HTML questions; they add no value. Make sure your edits address *all* the problems with a question instead. Thanks.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks, I will keep in mind. Just getting a bit more active on SO!